# Sqoop throwing "table or view does not exist" on table that appears to exist and have correct permissions

Tags: sqoop

Using sqoop v1 to import a view via [free-form query](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports) in an Oracle DB

```sh
sqoop import \
    -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=3144 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx1048m \
    -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.am.log.level=DEBUG \
    -Dmapreduce.map.log.level=DEBUG \
    -Dmapreduce.reduce.log.level=DEBUG \
    -Dmapred.job.name="Ora import table $tablename" \
    -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom \
    -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom \
    -Doraoop.timestamp.string=false \
    -Dmapreduce.map.max.attempts=10 \
    $oraclefile \
    --as-parquetfile \
    --target-dir $importdir \
    -query "select a.*, current_date as etl_date from $tablename a where 1=1 AND \$CONDITIONS" \
    --split-by $splitby \
    --where "1=1" \
    --num-mappers 12 \
    --delete-target-dir
```

and getting error

```sh
19/08/12 14:45:50 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Examining the output a bit more, I see the output

```sh
19/08/12 14:45:50 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select a.*, current_date as etl_date from MY_VIEW a where 1=1 AND (1 = 0)
```

Notice the "*AND (1 = 0)*" that sqoop is using for the `$CONDITIONS`. From discussions in the here comments and elsewhere, the 0=1 created in the sqoop statement is intended to by sqoop to fetch the table (in this case, view) columns.

Looking at the details of the offending view vs successful views in the same schema, they appear to have the same synonyms

[image]

and grants

[image]

making me doubt it is a permissions issue.

Does anyone know what could be happening here and why? Any debugging suggestion or fixes?

---

***Update**:

Looking on the oracle DB at some of the permissions that sqoop apparently needs to access oracle tables. Looking at some [articles](https://kirti-bi-solutions.blogspot.com/2017/12/sqoop-import-direct-option-ora-00942.html) that seemed related and trying to check the grants for a working view vs the non-working one, I saw...

```sql
SELECT * FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS;
<was blank (note I am not the DBA and there may be restrictions stopping me from seeing the "true" output)>

select Grantee,'Granted Through Role' as Grant_Type, role, table_name from role_tab_privs rtp, dba_role_privs drp where rtp.role = drp.granted_role and table_name = '<VIEW_THAT_WORKS>' union select Grantee,'Direct Grant' as Grant_type, null as role, table_name from dba_tab_privs where table_name = '<VIEW_THAT_WORKS>' ;

select Grantee,'Granted Through Role' as Grant_Type, role, table_name from role_tab_privs rtp, dba_role_privs drp where rtp.role = drp.granted_role and table_name = '<VIEW_THAT_NOT_WORKS>' union select Grantee,'Direct Grant' as Grant_type, null as role, table_name from dba_tab_privs where table_name = '<VIEW_THAT_NOT_WORKS>' ;

select a.*, current_date as etl_date from <VIEW_THAT_NOT_WORKS> a where (1 = 0)
```

and found that when checking the grants, for *both* the working and problematic views, I got the error

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

which is odd, since sqoop has no problem with the the other view.

Will trying turning on logging for the DB and seeing if can get more info on what exact query sqoop is sending that is causing the problem.

Comment: Why are you adding where 1=1 in the query and where clause. Please try removing both the options

Comment: @NehaJirafe AFK, but the code is a bit old but I recall that doing `...WHERE \$CONDITIONS` threw errors because sometimes the $CONDITIONS variable would be blank (producing an empty `WHERE`). Adding the "1=1" meant that if `$CONDITIONS` where blank, then we would still have a valid statement ("WHERE 1=1"). Again, IDK if this is really a problem since this same configuration has been working for many other similar tables we are importing. What do you think could be going wrong here with the 1=1 query?

Comment: From the sqoop code , Sqoop will build the SQL with where "1=0" in the intermediate state. Seems like the query creation had errors before it could complete. Hence I was wondering if the extra where is causing the issue. As far as my experience goes \$CONDITIONS is replaced by --where if present else "1=1"

Comment: @NehaJirafe Removing the "1=1" from both the `-query` and `--where` options did not change the results. Just for reference, could you link to where in the sqoop docs / code you saw this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the name of the view that I was giving to the **sqoop command was the views "real" name, when the view was given a differeing [synonym](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/synonyms.php)** in Oracle DB. Not experienced in Oracle DBA, so did not really think to look for this, but...

> Description
>
> A synonym is an alternative name for objects such as tables, views, sequences, stored procedures, and other database objects.
>
> You generally use synonyms when you are granting access to an object from another schema and you don't want the users to have to worry about knowing which schema owns the object.

I'm guessing that the problem was that (even though I could refer to the view by its "real" name in a query editor connected to the remote DB) for whatever reason sqoop was being rejected for not using the alias / synonym of the view.

**Using the view's synonym rather than the "real" name ran successfully.**

* While I did include a snippet of an image of the view's synonyms, I left out the actual synonym name (not knowing its importance) and also did not use the views actual name (used a placeholder name instead). This was done because was unconformable using the actual table names for privacy reasons. (So kinda shot myself in the foot there, in terms of getting a good answer from others).